What are the properties of natural numbers in metalanguage can be taken for granted when studying FOL, e.g., the proof of Gödel's theorem?
I have finished reading a textbook on first-order logic, formal arithmetic (Peano axioms), and Gödel's incompleteness theorem (ZFC not included). From the very beginning of the book, the authors emphasize the difference between proofs in the metalanguage and formal proofs. They use the notation $\mathbb{N}$ for natural numbers "in the common sense". Clearly, some properties of $\mathbb{N}$ need to be presumed, since otherwise, some terms used to define FOL itself, such as 'denumerably many individual variables $x_1,x_2,\ldots$', cannot be stated. In the proof of Gödel's incompleteness theorem, the properties for $\mathbb{N}$, such as unique factorization and induction are also widely used.
When studying other branches of math, I am comfortable with this treatment. However, formal arithmetic and Gödel's theorem are about natural numbers themselves and, in fact, imply the existence of nonstandard models of arithmetic. So, what are the properties of "standard" natural numbers in metalanguage can be taken for granted when studying FOL, e.g., the proof of Gödel's theorem?
Let me give an example. After introducing Peano's axioms in FOL, they showed by induction: For any $m$ and $n$,
$$\vdash \overline{m+n}=\overline{m}+\overline{n}, \mbox{ and } \vdash \overline{mn}=\overline{m}\cdot\overline{n}.$$
There are two points that are very subtle to me here.

The statement 'for any $m$ and $n$' is outside the formal system. FOL with PA seems unable to express a property that is true only for the set of standard natural numbers, that is, $\overline{0}, \overline{1}, \ldots$.

Why induction can be used outside the formal proof?



See e.g. this post as well as this one.

You shouldn't treat logic as different from other branches of mathematics. Treat the natural numbers in logic exactly the same way as any other branch of mathematics, with ordinary induction like you already know.

Think of PA as axioms for "Peano structures" exactly like how the group axioms are axioms for group structures. You can obviously use induction when studying groups, the same goes for Peano structures, they are just slightly complicated mathematical structures so why don't they get the privilege of induction?
